# restrict x-axis zoom & pan Flot time based chart

Tags: flot

I'm trying to use time based data in flot.

I have the chart plotting the data correctly and I have enabled panning and zooming.

My problem is that I cannot restrict the pan and zoom to a reasonable time period, for example, my data might span March 2011, but I am able to zoom out to a range from january 1900 to january 2100 and beyond.  The same with panning.

What I'd like to do is restrict panning and zooming to the year over which the data is available.  for the above example, zoom would be restricted to the year 2011 and a max zoom in of 1 day.  Panning would be restricted to the year 2011.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [zoomRange and panRange](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.navigate.js?r=306) options to the navigate plugin.

Comment: Link does not exist anymore. Because of this you should always put link and part of the code/text.